# Checkpoints in 'VS Apex Replay Debugger' doesn't expand the list variables

Tags: vs-code, apex-replay-debugger

Currently we are using checkpoints so that we can view the detailed data inside the list variable which is a limitation using breakpoints.If you look at the below screenshot it doesnt show the data inside the list.

[image]

In one of the dreamforce events, Apex Replay Debugger which was demoed (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JivDTfYvZ50) mentioning that the checkpoints will show the detailed list of variables as shown in the below pic.
[image]

I am getting the below error in the debug logs.

[image]